# Does oo-mox have a similar affect on Female ferengi?

Tags: star-trek, ferengi

In a lot of episodes of Star Trek involving the Ferengi, we see male Ferengi reacting to oo-mox (having their ear lobes rubbed).

It occurs to me that as far as I can remember it is only ever shown happening to a male. Ferengi females have smaller lobes, but I can't remember anything ever saying if oo-mox would or would not work on them as well.

Are there any canonical references that point that it would or would not work on a Ferengi female?

Comment: I don't recollect this been shown.  But I guess watching the episode where a female ferengi poses as a male trader might have something.

Comment: Given the social status of ferengi women it's doubtful the men ever bothered to find out...

Comment: Asking for a friend.

Answer (score -1):

Tv and movie canon I am %99 certain that this is never brought up however it may be in a book somewhere

Speculatively though it is doubtful that the nerve structure of the female differs greatly from the male so a female would probably derive some pleasure from oomax, it is possible due to a smaller surface area it would be even more pleasurable to a female, conversely the act may cause pain in females due to the same reason.

Due to Ferengi culture however performing oomax on a female would most likely be considered extremely deviant behavior.

Comment: This seems like guesswork. There's an obvious *anatomical* difference so there could just as easily be a  neurological difference too

Comment: There is an obvious anatomical difference in human males and females but nerve clusters are still in pretty much the same place, however it is speculation, I probably should have just left it at the first line.  Ultimately I suppose you cannot assume aliens sexual dimorphism would follow humans.

Comment: Yeah I am also 99% sure it has never come up in tv + movies. I think books might be the best bet or it may just never have been addressed. I read the memory alpha page on oo-mox before posting and it didn't mention gender at all.